# Is it possible to autoindent code in NetBeans in 1 second?

Tags: java, netbeans, indentation, auto-indent

I have this code:

```
static int kontrolaParityZavorek2(final char[] text, int zacatek) {
while (zacatek < text.length && jeOteviraciZavorka(text[zacatek])) {
int konec = kontrolaParityZavorek2(text, zacatek + 1);
if (konec >= text.length ||!jsouParove(text[zacatek], text[konec])) 
{throw new RuntimeException("Chybi uzaviraci zavorka na pozici: " + konec);}
zacatek = konec + 1;
}
return zacatek; 
}
```

I want to go to NetBeans, paste this code and autoindent the code in 1 second, so that it  looks like this:

```
static int kontrolaParityZavorek2(final char[] text, int zacatek) {
  while (zacatek < text.length && jeOteviraciZavorka(text[zacatek])) {
    int konec = kontrolaParityZavorek2(text, zacatek + 1);
    if (konec >= text.length ||!jsouParove(text[zacatek], text[konec])) 
    {throw new RuntimeException("Chybi uzaviraci zavorka na pozici: " + konec);}
    zacatek = konec + 1;
  }
  return zacatek; 
}
```

Is it possible?
If so, which key combination should I use or where in MENU can I find the function of AUTO INDENTING.

Answer (score 10):

Use the auto-formatter.

> Source -> Format

or

> Alt + Shift + F